# How to create a macro for microsoft word to concatenate first and last name to generate username

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, automation, vbscript, visual-basic

I am trying to create a document in MS word that I can use to auto-generate logins and passwords for my users by just entering in a few details. The form looks like this (sample):

**First Name:** John 
**Last Name:** Doe

The items that get auto-generated from the 2 fields above are below. Notice that it essentially uses the first letter of the first and last name to generate plus pre-defined letters/numbers that are appended or prepended:

**Network Username:** jdoe
**Network Password:** BRjd15!

**Email Username:** jdoe@company.com
**Email Password:** BRjd15!

**CRM Username:** jdoe@company.com
**CRM Password:** BRjd15!

**Skype Username:** jdoe.company
**Skype Password:** BRjd15!

**Phone Username:** jdoe@company.com
**Phone Password:** BRjd15!

I know how to create the formulas in Excel, but I am looking for this to be more like a form for ease-of-use with Word. If anyone has any other suggestions besides Word, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may create a "form" in Excel too;

Create the layout as a normal sheet.
At the end;

- Select the cells you want to be user-editable.
- Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd>, a dialogue opens.
- Find the `/Cell protection\` tab, and
- untick `[ ] Protection`.
- Close the dialogue with `OK`.
- Now set the sheet to be "Protected" from menus or the ribbon
  *("How" depends on version of Excel/LibreOffice)*.
- Save.

Anyone who doesn't know how to "Unprotect" the sheet will have access only to the cells you selected above.

*The facts above based on LibreOffice Calc, should be the same in Excel*

Comment: This is what I actually ended up doing. Though I'm using a Mac (Office 2011) and I guess text fields don't work on it. You need some ActiveX Form Controls, which are only on the PC version. Thanks for the input.

Comment: On all StackExchange sites the "tick" at the upper left of the "answer" is for marking it as "good", please do that :-)